# Get Numpy genfromtxt converter to use def function

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I have searched through the forums and cannot seem to work out the following problem.  I am very new to python with a little programming experience so my issue might be trivial.

The want to convert a date-time string to date-time format using `date.strptime` classmethod.

The problem is the string format within the column is **not consistent** (majority are `%Y-%m-%d $H:$M:$S.%f`) ; when the time falls exactly on the second, the millisecond decimals are omitted (format should be instead `%Y-%m-%d $H:$M:$S`).  When the `strptime` encounters an unrecognized format, it will simply place a `None` value in the array element.

Is there any way to create an exception in the `lambda` function (i.e., `ValueError` exception), if not, how do I pass the string value into a "normal" `def timeConv(x)` function from the `genfromtxt` converter option?

Maybe there is a better way of approaching this problem...?

My current code which results in a `None` value when the format is `%Y-%m-%d $H:$M:$S`:

```
timeConv = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '\"%Y-%m-%d $H:$M:$S.%f\"')

Time = np.genfromtxt(file, dtype='object', delimiter=',', skip_header=4, usecols=(0), converters = {0: timeConv})
```

Comment: fyi, `f = lambda x, y: <do things with x, y>` is the same as `def f(x, y): <do things with x, y>` and both give the name `f` to the function `<...>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `try..except` to first try one format, and if it does not work, catch the exception and try the other format:

```
import datetime as DT
import numpy as np

def timeConv(x):
    try:
        return DT.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    except ValueError as err:
        return DT.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

time = np.genfromtxt(file, dtype='object', delimiter=',', skip_header=4,
                     usecols=(0), converters = {0: timeConv})
```

The function, `timeConv` is passed to `genfromtxt` the same way you passed the `lambda`.

---

The [dateutil module](http://niemeyer.net/python-dateutil) has a date string parser which does not require you to specify the exact format of the date string. So using dateutil you could simply write

```
import dateutil.parser as dparser
import numpy as np

time = np.genfromtxt(file, dtype='object', delimiter=',', skip_header=4,
                     usecols=(0), converters = {0: dparser.parse})
```

Note that although `dparser.parse` is very easy to use, there are some ambiguous date strings like `2013-8-9` (August 8 or Sept 9?) which require more care. Be sure to read up on the `dayfirst` and `yearfirst` parameters so you can control the parser's behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much!  The first section of code worked like a charm.  Also, thanks for letting me know about the dateutil.parser, I was unware this existed.  cheers-A